# Is hunger stress tracked like other stress tracks?

Tags: dresden-files, fate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happens when a character's feeding stress track is maxed out?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/11161/what-happens-when-a-characters-feeding-stress-track-is-maxed-out)

I've looked at this [question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/11161/what-happens-when-a-characters-feeding-stress-track-is-maxed-out), and it assumes that the Hunger Stress track is tracked like the other stress tracks. Namely, at the end of a scene, you take an attack against your Hunger, and defend against it with Discipline. If you succeed in your defense, nothing happens and anything you had in the stress track from previous scenes in which you failed.

However, in my game today, it came up that the rules as written could be interpreted a different way. Relevant section YS 190:

> At the end of a scene whenever you have heavily exerted your affected
>   powers, you must check to see if you experience a feeding failure.
>   This manifests as an attack with a strength equal to the total refresh
>   cost of the abilities you used;
>
> [...]
>   If you fail, you take hunger stress as though you'd suffered an attack. If you have physical or mental consequence slots open, you may use them to buy off the stress as per the normal rules (page 203).
>
> **If you cannot or do not wish to spare consequences, then you must lose access to a number of your powers, up to a refresh cost equal to
>   the amount of stress taken.**

In the emphasized section, it can be inferred that if you take damage, and cannot spare consequences, you **must** lose access to your powers.

So, we're at a bit of an impasse. I lean towards the reading that it is a normal stress track, and you only need to lose powers or take consequences if you are over your stress track, but because of the wording of that section it is a bit unclear.

Comment: I just realized, I'd asked this question before and gotten an answer from him: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/11161/what-happens-when-a-characters-feeding-stress-track-is-maxed-out?rq=1

Comment: @wraith808 I'm conservative on declaring things exact duplicates, but I'd say this one *is*. Both questions are asking for clarifications of the ambiguous wording on how hunger stress affects powers, and the answers to either fit both. They should be merged. (As a bonus to voting to close as duplicate, this topic will get marked as a FAQ about DFRPG.)